# Angular2 : How to capture all user event

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to capture all the user events on the screen. Eg. If user hovers on button or clicks button or type in input field etc.

There are lots of component throughout the application. What is the common place to do it, either by creating a directive or something else?

Comment: I think Observables can help you with that http://reactivex.io/rxjs/.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a good idea. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to capture all events?

Comment: I need to track user behaviour on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this can help you.

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(ev:KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(`The user just pressed ${ev.key}!`);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseup(event: MouseEvent) { this.mouseup.emit(event); }

  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) { this.mousemove.emit(event); }
```